# Duplicates on x-axis heatmap Plotly

Tags: plotly, heatmap

So, most importantly I need to know how to get the duplicate x-values on the x-axis of a plotly heatmap. I tried the following code on the example below, but it doesn't return what I want. Instead I want two a's on the x-axis.:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Heatmap(z=[[1,2], [3,4]],x=["a","a"],y=["b","c"]))
fig.update_layout(             
    title="simple example",     
    xaxis={'ticktext':["a","a"],'tickvals':[0,1]})
fig.write_html('figure.html', auto_open=True)
```

[image: Example]